# In ServiceStack what is the proper way to get the container

Tags: inversion-of-control, servicestack

I'm currently attempting to use ServiceStack in a SignalR application that I am writing that is part of a large MVC 4.5 application.

I currently have a class in the App_Start folder that is starting my Hub. My question is how do I get a reference to the container as shown in the wiki for ServiceStack.

```
container.Register<IRedisClientsManager>(c => new PooledRedisClientManager("localhost:6379"));
container.Register<ICacheClient>(c => (ICacheClient)c.Resolve<IRedisClientsManager>().GetCacheClient());
```

What I am doing is using Redis as the Development cache tier and planning on using our exisitng membase as the production cache tier.

How do I get container?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To resolve dependencies from ServiceStack's IOC outside servicestack you can use either:

```
var foo = HostContext.TryResolve<IFoo>(); //null if doesn't exist
var foo = HostContext.Resolve<IFoo>();    //throws if IFoo doesn't exist
```

There are a few to access the Container outside from of outside of ServiceStack, the quickest way is:

```
var container = HostContext.Container;
```

### Via the AppHost singleton

Which is a shorthand way of accessing it via the `IAppHost` singleton:

```
HostContext.AppHost.Container
```

Comment: EndpointHost is now Endpoint.  Correct?  Also, it appears that AppHost is no longer under Endpoint.  Will AppHostBase.Instance return the same?

Comment: @FredLackey No that was for v3, updated it to use v4.

Comment: Not sure, but in version 3.9.48, I didn't get this option under HostContext.. However, the I could resolve the dependencies using "AppHostBase.Instance.Container.Resolve<T>()" method.